# jQuery click fires without click in that loop. Console does not print inside loop data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this very small code, and it created lots of issue with me...

I tried everything and our console shows what is happening. And our icon width is always greater than 70. In fact, it is 130 as per console. Then why is jQuery firing a click event when I have clearly instructed to go in that loop when width is less than equal to 70?

```
if($scope.data.icon_width <= '70')
{
    console.log($scope.data.icon_width);
    console.log('lessthan70');

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#random_pattern291,#random_pattern292,#random_pattern293").click(function()
        {
            $scope.data.background_pic ='';
        });
    });
}
else
{
    console.log($scope.data.icon_width);
    console.log($scope.data.background_pic);
}
```

Our console prints the dimension from the *else* loop as the icon width is more than 70. I.e, 130, but when I click any of these ids, #random_pattern291, #random_pattern292, #random_pattern293, the icon_width check is ignored. It executes the function and I can see in console.log which says width is 130.

To make it more strange I never see this console.log('lessthan70') when we click these buttons, so it may sound that it's not entering into that loop, but that is a wrong assumption.

I have these three buttons, click event only, at one place and when I comment this part,

```
  //    $scope.data.background_pic ='';
```

then my picture remains picture. It means when I click on these buttons then it is setting the background_pic ='', so I am 100% sure this is being fired. But why?

Why is console.log('lessthan70') not being displayed?  But these buttons are fired when clearly the console shows that the width is 130.

We tried all sorts of things, like an on change event. Everything. Nothing works.

I even tried this:

```
if ($scope.data.icon_width <== '70')


if ($scope.data.icon_width <==  70)

if ($scope.data.icon_width <=   70)
```

Comment: @freedomn-m can u plz tell how ??

Comment: @freedomn-m not working. i changed this to this but same result.    var numberecheck =Number("70");
   if($scope.data.icon_width <= numberecheck)

Comment: @freedomn-m  tried these two combination. still same result   // var numberecheck = Number($scope.data.icon_width);
 var numberecheck = parseInt($scope.data.icon_width);

   if(numberecheck <= 70)

Comment: try if (parseInt($scope.data.icon_width) <=   70)

Comment: btw, what is this code even trying to do?  It looks very, very confused.  Where is the icon width getting set to 130?  In the css or class for that element? Why would it change from less than 70 to 130?  Just start again, and write the requirement in plain language.